# glViewport like camera

Tags: lwjgl

I'm using glViewport as a camera of sorts, but I'm not quite sure how it works. For example when I change do:

```
glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);
glViewport(0, 0, 400, 200);
```

It makes the viewing area larger rather than just viewing a 400x200 area...

Answer (score 1):

[glViewport](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glViewport.xml) sets the viewport of your application. The viewport should be set to the size of your screen, window, canvas (for webgl) or texture you are rendering to.

[glOrtho](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) sets the selected matrix parallel projection matrix, which can be used as a camera. Calling it like in the following sample lets you control the position with the `x`and `y` variables while allowing you to change the size with the `width`and `height` variables.

```
float left = x - width / 2;
float right = x + width / 2;
float bottom = y + height / 2;
float top = y - width / 2;
glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`glViewport` is a ***completely*** different transformation than you think it is. What `glViewport` actually does is re-map the scene *after* projection.

In OpenGL, the scene always projects to a special coordinate space where the viewing volume is defined by a cube: [**-1**,**1**] (following division by `W`). The location (-1,-1,-1) is the bottom-left of your viewport at the near clip plane. The location (1,1,1) is the top-right of your viewport at the far clip plane. Your projection matrix produces coordinates in a special coordinate space called *clip-space*, and the *clip-space* coordinates are divided by `W` to produce the NDC coordinates described above.

Thus, the only thing that `glViewport` actually does is define ***where within your window*** that your projected image is displayed. It will effectively stretch the scene, and I do not think that is what you want. To display a 400x200 area, you need to alter your projection matrix as well so that you do not simply compress your projected scene into a smaller area.

#### Consider the following instead:

```
glOrtho    (0, 400, 200, 0,    -1, 1);
glViewport (0, 0,   400, 200);
```